# Как узнать mobile responsive сайт или нет при отображении в WebView

Tags: java, android, android-webview

У меня есть перечень сайтов, которые я отображаю в `WebView`, можно ли как-то узнать заранее, перед отображением, является ли веб-сайт `mobile responsive` или нет?

Я имею ввиду, как узнать, что верстка веб-сайта адаптирована под мобильный телефон. Например, я не хочу отображать сайты, которые не адаптированы.

пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что именно такое mobile responsive? Как этот сайт отличить от обычного?

Comment: @metalurgus Под не mobile responsive я имею ввиду сайты у которых верстка не адаптирована под мобильные устройства, например текст не помещается на всю ширину экрана.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Однозначно детектировать адаптивную верстку, в общем случае, думаю, невозможно.

Можно, конечно, попробовать поискать характерные ей черты, вроде мета тега `viewport` и подобных вещей, но, в общем случае, это работать не будет.

Как вариант, можно довериться [сервису от Google](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/) и спрашивать у него. В случае, если по мнению этого сервиса, сайт имеет адаптивную верстку, то он Вам скажет, что:

> Отлично! Страница оптимизирована для мобильных устройств.

в противном случае, Вы получите:

> Не оптимизировано для мобильных устройств

Иными словами, перед отображением сайта, делаете запрос к этому сервису и парсите результат, если все ок – показываете страницу, если нет – то нет.

Comment: а можно как-то из телефона программно проверить сайт с помощью этого сервиса от  Google? у него есть свой API?

Comment: @Lucky_girl, API я не нашел, но в своем приложении Вы можете взаимодействовать с этим сервисом посредством GET-запросов.